Getting Permission Error while trying to pin a shortcut to the Start Menu with PowerShell
In an Admin PowerShell terminal, I am trying to pin a shortcut from Desktop to the Start Menu, but it's giving me a permission error.
I have tried different verbs, such as Open, and it works perfectly fine, but I get this error on pinning to the Start Menu:
$desktopPath  = [System.Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')
$shortcutName = "XAMPP Control Panel.lnk"  # Name of the shortcut
$shortcutPath = Join-Path $desktopPath $shortcutName

$Shell  = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$Folder = $Shell.Namespace((Get-Item $shortcutPath).DirectoryName)
$Item   = $Folder.ParseName((Get-Item $shortcutPath).Name)

$Item.Verbs() | ForEach-Object { Write-Output $_.Name }
$Verb = $Item.Verbs() | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "&Pin to Start"}
  if ($Verb) {
    $Verb.DoIt()
    Write-Output "Pinned."
  } else {
    Write-Output "The item is already pinned or cannot be pinned."
  }


    &Open
      Open file location

    &Add to archive...
      Add to "XAMPP Control Panel.rar"

      Compress and email...
        Compress to "XAMPP   Control Panel.rar" and email

      Run as administrator
        Edit with VS Code
        Open with Code
        Troubleshoot compatibility

    &Pin to Start
      Edit with Notepad++
      Scan with Microsoft Defender...
      Restore previous versions
      Share with Send Anywhere SM-N9750
      Cut

    &Copy
      Create shortcut

    &Delete
      Rename
      Properties

    Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005(E_ACCESSDENIED))
      At line:12 char:5
        +   $Verb.DoIt()
        +   ~~~~~~~~~~~~
          + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], UnauthorizedAccessException
          + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException


    Pinned.



I have also tried via Group Policy:

Run: gpedit.msc → User Configuration → Administrative Templates → Start Menu and Taskbar

Disabled: Prevent users from customizing their Start Screen  


Rebooted to ensure change was applied, yet result was the same


Please don’t screenshot terminal output - instead, please copy/paste the output into a code box

@JW0914 Sure. I will correct it now

The pasted content was malformed so I made some logical inferences, however please verify the modifications I made are accurate to the Line 12, Character 5 error, and if Line 12 from the terminal is no longer Line 12 in the code box [$Verb.DoIt()], please modify the error Line number in the code box to accurately reflect whatever line was the error

[Edit] your question to include the values of each of your variables before the loop executes.

@JW0914 - $Verb.DoIt() is the problem. The PowerShell error itself indicates what failed to execute.

@Ramhound. Thanks for your response. I am unsure about it being the problem because as I mentioned above I used $Verb.DoIt() with the verb "OPEN" and it worked fine.

@ArashSeifi - Since I can't run the PowerShell script myself, I am forced to ask the results of the diagnostics, I would perform.  If the error calls out $Verb.DoIt() then that is the problem. I can't find any documentation on Open, only DoIt, so you will have to provide that documentation for us.

@Ramhound. You are correct, There seem to be no documents on the "&Open" verb. But it's not something special. It just opens the file you define its path(Like double-clicking it). You can see it in the code I mentioned, which is the list of available verbs(actions) a particular app can do(Like right-clicking it). I have also tried with "$Item.InvokeVerb($Verb.Name)", here I get no errors but 0 effect.
